# CSS button has extra margin from somewhere

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where a button on my web page does not display as it should. It displays with an unwanted black margin around it. The button that says send is the problem. What I want it to display is the button on its own in the top left-hand corner of the area that is designated for it. The background is supposed to be there. The problem is where the button is, not the background itself Instead of doing this, it displays somewhere in the middle

```css
.modal {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 background-color: #474e5d;
 position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
 z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
 }
.modal-content {
 border-radius: 25px;
 background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto auto auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 50%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}
.title { 
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family:'Zorque';
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:80px;
 margin-bottom:80px;
}
.enter-label {
 display: block;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:60px;
 margin-bottom:60px;
}
.enter {
    text-align:center;
}
#nameyourself {
 text-align:center;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: "Zorque";
 src:url("/client/img/Zorque.woff") format("woff")
}
.input {
 text-align:center;
 padding-left:60px;
 padding-right:60px;
 padding-top: 16px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
}
#chat {
    /*display:none;*/
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#messagebox {
    border: 0; 
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 90%;
    height:10%;
    margin:0;
}
.submitButton {
}
#chatForm{
    background: #033;
}
#msgs {
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:90%;
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    margin:0;
}
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }

#messages li { 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    background: black; 
    color:#eee;
}
#messages li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #eee; 
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Group Chat</title>
    <link id="favicon" rel="icon" href="https://cdn.glitch.com/ad2a2be0-9feb-4eb9-8151-2f9d1202b0b7%2Ffavicon.ico?1540848159347" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <script src="/client.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chat">
        <div id="msgs">
            <ul id="messages"></ul>
        </div>
        <form id="chatForm">
            <input id="messagebox" required>
            <button class="submitButton">
              Send
          </button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As your css shows your button has not any style here. So it get its style from other css. Use your browser inspector to found the problem

Comment: The problem is from the input with `messagebox` id. what is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#messagebox {
    border: 0; 
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 90%;
    height:10%;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.submitButton {
    margin:0;padding:10px;width: 10%;box-sizing: border-box;
    height:10%;background: #033;float:right;border:0;color:white;cursor: pointer;
}
#chatForm{
    /*background: #033;*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 elements in your form.
Just use `<br>` after `<input id="messagebox" required>`

Comment: The problem isn't that the background exists, it's that the button is in the middle of the background instead of being in the top lefthand corner

Comment: as you can see you have one more elements inside your form thats why your button in the right corner
`code`
<input id="messagebox" required>
<button class="submitButton">Send</button>
`code`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your `#messagebox` element in one line with the `button`. The `#messagebox` gets the whole space and move your button to the right side of this page. Remove `width: 90%` property and it should work ok. However, I'm not sure what is the final design.

Please read about block/inline elements for information how to build the proper HTML/CSS structure.

Example article:
[block-level and inline elements](https://codeburst.io/block-level-and-inline-elements-the-difference-between-div-and-span-2f8502c1f95b)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding these specific rules to your CSS:

```
#chatForm {
  display: flex;
}

.submitButton {
  flex: 1;
}
```

[image: before]
[image]